# How to prevent copy elision when implementing custom array functionality?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-elision

I'm writing a class `CValue` in C++, which is supposed to be an analog of values in JavaScript. `CValue` object can be almost every type, depending on initialization/assignment: primitive value (`bool`, `int`, `double`, string objects, etc.), array, or even an object (a hash map with property names as keys and `CValue` as values). All work just fine, but I have some troubles with arrays and object element access. I will explain the problem for arrays.

To access elements of an array, `CValue` has the following method:

```cpp
CValue CValue::operator[](int index)
```

Notice, that I return `CValue`, not `CValue&` - that is because the object on which this operator was called may not be an array. In that case I just return empty `CValue`, which is like `undefined` from JS. When I call `operator[]` on a valid array value and given index is correct, then I return a reference-like `CValue` object, which contains a pointer to actually stored element in the array under the hood. This value is not a copy of original array element, because I want to be able to change it like so:

```cpp
arr[0] = 42;
```

If I were returning a copy of array element, then, obviously, I would change its *copy*, not the original element.

So I only need to return reference-like `CValue` objects when I access elements of arrays (or objects). In other scenarios I just make a copy of another value. For example:

```cpp
CValue var1 = 42;
CValue var2 = var1;  // var1 = 42, var2 = 42
var2 = 100;          // var1 = 42, var2 = 100
```

---

And now, finally, I can describe the problem to you. When I write

```cpp
CValue var = arr[0];
```

compiler thinks, that it is a great opportunity for him to use copy elision, and instead of using copy constructor (which will make a copy of value) it just replaces newly created value with reference-like `CValue` object, returned from `operator[]`. This leads to following unwanted behaviour:

```cpp
arr[0] = 42;
CValue var = arr[0];  // var = 42,  arr[0] = 42
var = 100;            // var = 100, arr[0] = 100
```

I can use variable `var` to fully access first element of `arr`. But I just wanted to make a copy of it. So my question is:

How can I prevent copy elision here to avoid this unwanted begaviour?

NOTE: I know I can disable it completely in compiler flags, but I don't want to do this, because copy elision is quite useful overall.

---

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

I use MSVS 2019 compiler. The MRE is quite big, but I cut it down as much as I could.

```cpp
// cvalue.h
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class IBaseValue;
class CPrimitive;
class CArray;

// wrapper around IBaseValue (see below) with specific value type
class CTypedValue
{
public:
    enum ValueType
    {
        vtUndefined,
        vtInteger,
        vtArray
    };

public:
    CTypedValue();

public:
    std::shared_ptr<IBaseValue> m_value;
    ValueType m_type;
};

// Container for CTypedValue which is also allows to treat typed value as reference
class CTypedValueContainer
{
public:
    CTypedValueContainer();
    CTypedValueContainer(const CTypedValueContainer& other);

    CTypedValueContainer& operator=(const CTypedValueContainer& other);

public:
    std::shared_ptr<CTypedValue> m_typedValue;
    bool m_isReference;
};

// Main class
class CValue
{
public:
    CValue();
    CValue(int value);
    CValue(const CValue& other);

    ~CValue();

    CValue& operator=(const CValue& other);

    static CValue createArray(int size);

    bool IsUndefined();
    operator int();
    CValue operator[](int index);

private:
    CTypedValueContainer* m_internal;
};

// Base class for value types
class IBaseValue
{
public:
    IBaseValue() = default;
    virtual ~IBaseValue() = default;
};

// Primitive value type (only with int type for MRE)
class CPrimitive : public IBaseValue
{
public:
    CPrimitive(int value);

    int toInt();

private:
    int m_value;
};

// Array value type
class CArray : public IBaseValue
{
public:
    CArray(int size);

    CValue& get(int i);

private:
    std::vector<CValue> m_values;
};
```

```cpp
// cvalue.cpp
#include "cvalue.h"

CPrimitive::CPrimitive(int value) : m_value(value)
{
}

int CPrimitive::toInt()
{
    return m_value;
}

CArray::CArray(int size) : m_values(size)
{
}

CValue& CArray::get(int i)
{
    return m_values[i];
}

CTypedValue::CTypedValue() : m_type(vtUndefined)
{
}

CTypedValueContainer::CTypedValueContainer() : m_typedValue(new CTypedValue()), m_isReference(false)
{
}

CTypedValueContainer::CTypedValueContainer(const CTypedValueContainer& other) : CTypedValueContainer()
{
    *this = other;
}

CTypedValueContainer& CTypedValueContainer::operator=(const CTypedValueContainer& other)
{
    if (other.m_isReference)
        m_typedValue = other.m_typedValue;
    else
        *m_typedValue = *other.m_typedValue;
    return *this;
}

CValue::CValue() : m_internal(new CTypedValueContainer)
{
}

CValue::CValue(int value) : CValue()
{
    m_internal->m_typedValue->m_value = std::make_shared<CPrimitive>(value);
    m_internal->m_typedValue->m_type = CTypedValue::vtInteger;
}

CValue::CValue(const CValue& other) : m_internal(new CTypedValueContainer(*other.m_internal))
{
}

CValue::~CValue()
{
    delete m_internal;
}

CValue CValue::createArray(int size)
{
    CValue ret;
    ret.m_internal->m_typedValue->m_value = std::make_shared<CArray>(size);
    ret.m_internal->m_typedValue->m_type = CTypedValue::vtArray;
    return ret;
}

CValue& CValue::operator=(const CValue& other)
{
    *m_internal = *other.m_internal;
    return *this;
}

bool CValue::IsUndefined()
{
    return m_internal->m_typedValue->m_type == CTypedValue::vtUndefined;
}

CValue::operator int()
{
    if (m_internal->m_typedValue->m_type != CTypedValue::vtInteger)
        return 0;
    return static_cast<CPrimitive*>(m_internal->m_typedValue->m_value.get())->toInt();
}

CValue CValue::operator[](int index)
{
    if (m_internal->m_typedValue->m_type != CTypedValue::vtArray)
        return CValue();
    CValue& value = static_cast<CArray*>(m_internal->m_typedValue->m_value.get())->get(index);
    value.m_internal->m_isReference = true;
    return value;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "cvalue.h"

int main()
{
    // Normal copy
    CValue var1 = 42;
    CValue var2 = var1;
    std::cout << "var1 = " << (int)var1 << ", var2 = " << (int)var2 << std::endl;
    var2 = 100;
    std::cout << "var1 = " << (int)var1 << ", var2 = " << (int)var2 << std::endl;
    // Copy of array element
    CValue arr = CValue::createArray(1);
    arr[0] = 42;
    CValue var = arr[0];
    std::cout << "var = " << (int)var << ",  arr[0] = " << (int)arr[0] << std::endl;
    var = 100;
    std::cout << "var = " << (int)var << ", arr[0] = " << (int)arr[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

Here some output that this program produce. I compiled it with MinGW GCC compiler, since it has opportunity to disable copy elisions.

`g++ main.cpp cvalue.cpp`:

```
var1 = 42, var2 = 42
var1 = 42, var2 = 100
var = 42,  arr[0] = 42
var = 100, arr[0] = 100
```

`g++ main.cpp cvalue.cpp -fno-elide-constructors`:

```
var1 = 42, var2 = 42
var1 = 42, var2 = 100
var = 42,  arr[0] = 42
var = 100, arr[0] = 42
```

Second output is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Instead of describing what the code does just post the working code and then describe the expected output and how it is different from your current output.

Comment: *"I know I can disable it completely in compiler flags, but I don't want to do this,"* Compiler is allowed to do anything under the [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule) as long as...

Comment: Feels like you just need std::map, or std::unordered_map

Comment: I do not see how this has anything to do with a copy elision, `CValue var = arr[0];` calls a constructor of `CValue` with the result of `arr[0]` evaluation. It is up to you to define what this does and I think you defined it incorrectly w.r.t your expectations - provide a [mcve].

Comment: @user12002570 Well, you don't actually need to run or debug any code to understand my question, but I will try to provide MRE in updated post as soon as I can.

Comment: If `arr[x]` returns a "reference-like CValue object, which contains a pointer to actually stored element in the array under the hood", I don't see how copy elision breaks that. How do you handle reads and writes to such "reference-like" objects?

Comment: @asethone My point is that the problem can be unrelated to copy elision. So unless you show us the exact working code, we won't be able to answer or diagnose the exact problem. There may be ways to solve the problem but only if you show us the exact code.

Comment: There is no difference between `CValue var2 = var1;` and `CValue var = arr[0];`. If you want them to behave differently, you need to return something else from `operator[]`. The conventional way is to return a "proxy object" rather than the element itself.

Comment: if the returned `CValue` encapsulates the reference then it should not matter whether the copy is elided or not. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Always provide a MRE if possible. Even if you believe it is not necessary to have one to understand your problem, it has been proven again and again this is usually not actually the case. You believe a MRE is not needed  only because you are familiar with what you're working with and project the assumption on others.

Comment: Change your operator to be `CValueRef CValue::operator[](int index)`, and define a constructor `CValue::CValue(CValueRef)` that does the copying. Yes this does mean essentially duplicating your class

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, I thought about it too, but the idea of completely copying the class content scares me.

Comment: The other option is to have `CValue` have reference semantics *everywhere*, and provide a `copy` member function.

Comment: @Caleth That is a good idea too. But as I said, I'm trying to reproduce JS variables behaviour and semantic.

Comment: if you try to use C++ as javascript you will fail miserably one way or another. Or many many ways.

Comment: Another option is to change `operator[]` to be able to return a reference. You could add an `undefined` entry to the array when it is accessed out-of-range, and return that reference

Comment: @Caleth Hmm, that should actually work, though it seems a little bit kludgy. Thanks for the great ideas!

Comment: @asethone it also matches how js handles `arr[index] = blah`

Comment: @Quimby, @molbdnilo When I write `arr[0] = 42;` the assignment operator is called on `CValue` instance, returned from `operator[]`. So copy constructor is called once here, right? But when I write `CValue var = arr[0];` why does copy constructor still get called once? Isn't it because of copy elision?

Comment: your mistake is that `CValue var=arr[0];` DOES NOT invoke `operator=` as-per language rules. it calls  eligible constructor for `var`. `arr[0]=42` causes creation of a new returned object by `operator[]` and `operator=` is applied to it. Tbh whole thing  works backwards. It is supposed to be a COW class, but designed weirdly

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I know, that `CValue var = arr[0];` works the same way as `CValue var(arr[0]);`. But the question is still the same: why in both `arr[0] = 42;` and `CValue var(arr[0]);` there is only one call to `CValue` copy constructor? Could you explain me this?
And yes, `CValue` was supposed to be COW. And actually **it is COW**, until we work with arrays. The first 5 lines of _main.cpp_ shows that.

Comment: it's result of `return value;` in `operator[]`. It's same as you wrote `CValue var(value);` what you want is `Value value` in a const-qualified version of `operator[]` because `=arr[0]` and `arr[0]=` must be different operations for a COW

Comment: another solution would be `CValueReference operator[]`, where `CValueReference` is simply a wrapper, which accepts `CValue&` and can be cast to `CValue` or can facilitate an assignment of compatible values. Seems your `CValue` tries do both jobs

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie "> It's same as you wrote CValue var(value);". Yes it is. But why? Again, what I am trying to understand: I copy `CValue` once on returning from `operator[]` - this is obvious, since I can call `arr[0] = 42` on that copy; then it should be **another copy** to `var` in line `CValue var(arr[0]);`. But actually there is only ONE copy in this line, which you can test by yourself. If there were 2 copies, it would produce the desired result.

Comment: @asethone let's say that operator's code is same as `return CValue(value)` (because return type is `CValue` and `value` is of diffeent value cathegory. Then `CValue var(CValue(value));` that's guaranteed (since C++17) copy elision. You can write  `CValue var(CValue(CValue(value)));`, etc., an instance is not materialized until needed . Reliance on the side-effect of ctor is an UB before C++17.

Comment: So, we have come to the conclusion that it is because of copy elision, even so some people here was trying to ensure me that it is not. I'm glad we finally figured it out. So I guess there is no other way than returning object of another class from `operator[]` for providing desired functionality?

Comment: In C++17 and up, there is no copy elision in this context. People sometimes refer to what happens as "mandatory or guaranteed copy elision", but it isn't. There is no copy in the first place so there is nothing to elide. https://godbolt.org/z/fhz65c6K8

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It seems, that since C++17 you can't disable that behaviour with `-fno-elide-constructors` flag, because "URVO is no longer considered a form of copy elision" ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#:~:text=URVO%20is%20mandatory%20and%20no%20longer%20considered%20a%20form%20of%20copy%20elision%3B%20see%20above.)). Apparently in C++11 this is still considered a copy elision.

Comment: It's a misnomer. What's mandatory isn't an optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that many in the comments denied that incorrect behavior arises due to copy elision, it is so. You can check out **OUTPUT** section in my original question to see that.

To avoid that, I had to change program architecture, adding `CValueRef` class, that implementing reference-like behaviour for `CValue`, instead of mixing all this functionality in `CValue`. Seems, that there is no other way, but returning an object of another class from `operator[]`, because in line

```cpp
CValue var = arr[0];
```

`var` initializes as reference-like object, returned from that operator, instead of initializing as copy of it.

Thanks a lot to @Caleth and @Swift - Friday Pie.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, it should be obvious now, but the original idea was working with only one universal `CValue` class. This idea still seems impossible to me, because of how `operator[]` is supposed to work. The MRE code in the question is really close to what I wanted to achieve, but copy elision causes some unwanted behaviour, which I've already described. So, yeah, returning `CValueRef` solves this.